# php shell_exec() mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql, linux, shell

shell script:

```
if [ id > 0 ]
then
    /usr/bin/mysql -uuser -p"$pass" database"$id" < database"$id".sql
    echo $id
fi
done < $file
```

if I run it through terminal, everything works perfectly. 
But when I use php function shell_exec()

```
 shell_exec("/home/g/user/shellfile.sh")
```

output is id variable (as expected), script executes too fast, and no changes in database. Why so?

Comment: Try using the full pathname to `database"$id".sql`.

Comment: is php executing under a different user context, lacking permissions to execute?... check PHP logs for error output

Comment: @Barmar did it, nothing changed

Comment: if thewe were lack of permissions to execute, script wouldn't run at all, I think. No errors in log.

Comment: Try capturing output and printing the result. `echo shell_exec("/home/g/user/shellfile.sh 2>&1")`

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot, I added 2>&1 and now everything works just fine

Comment: That couldn't have made it work. The purpose was to find out why it's NOT working.

Comment: Now the problem is: usr/bin/mysql:not found, because of permissions?